# OLE_COLOR conversion in PHP

Tags: php, vb.net

I am writing a script in PHP and need to call a method that takes and OLE_COLOR as an argument.  I've tried everything I can think of and what others have suggested so far, and the best I can get is a type mismatch error.  These are the data type instructions for various languages from the API provider:

> C++: static_cast(RGB(0, 0, 255))
>
> VB6: RGB(0, 0, 255)
>
> VB.NET:
>   Convert.ToUInt32(System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.FromArgb(0,
>   0, 255))
>
> C#: (uint)System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.FromArgb(0, 0,
>   255))
>
> Others: 32 bit integer value in following format: 0x00bbggrr (in BGR
>   format, not in RGB)

The method prototype is:

```
Sub AddHyperlink(InputFileName As String,
                 OutputFileName As String,
                 From As Long,
                 To As Long,
                 Left As Double,
                 Top As Double,
                 Right As Double,
                 Bottom As Double,
                 Url As String,
                 Style As prcAnnotBorderStyle,
                 Color As OLE_COLOR)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`OLE_COLOR` in Windows is an integer in the format of 0x00bbggrr. That means `color = red + 256 * green + 65536 * blue`, where each component is in the range of 0-255. 0x000000ff is pure red, 0x0000ff00 is pure green, 0x00ff0000 is pure blue.